# Flutter NetworkImage failed to load HEIC image from url

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter, image-load

In my NetworkImage my url is this
https://joylist.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/profile/5f229e9cfa3dc8542f815cb9.HEIC

And it throws this exception
[image]

It worked fine with .jpg or png and other formats. Now, How can I resolve this and show this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the heic to jpg library (https://pub.dev/packages/heic_to_jpg) to achieve this (Except that you're specifically looking to show HEIC images).

Add the package:

```
dependencies:
  heic_to_jpg: ^0.1.2
```

Import the package in your dart file:

```
import 'package:heic_to_jpg/heic_to_jpg.dart';
```

And call convert method with local HEIC/HEIF image file path.

```
String jpegPath = await HeicToJpg.convert(heicPath);
```